# How to remove the number of a particular charpter in a RST file?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

While using Python Sphinx making a latex file, I want to remove the chapter number of given chapters because they are strictly speaking just a transition text describing the chapters followed.

For example, my toctree looks like this

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

   intro
   part_one 
   chapter_one
   chapter_two
   part_two
   chapter_three 
   chapter_four
```

Here, `intro`, `part_one` and `part_two` are descriptive texts that are NOT part of the chapters. So, I don't want them have chapter numbers while not interrupting the numbering for the "real" chapters.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Sphinx out of the box.  It's all or nothing with numbering.  See "Section numbering" under http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree